# Unable to fetch json from html page using AngularJS $http.get

Tags: html, json, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I am having a strange issue. I am able to fetch the json in [www.w3schools.com/angular/customers.php](http://www.w3schools.com/angular/customers.php) using $http.get. However, when I added the same json to a html page in my server (which does not have any html tags), am not able to fetch it. Below is the code I am using for http.get:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get("http://www.xxxxxxx.com/temp/htmlpage1.html")
    .success(function(response) {alert('success');$scope.names = response.records;})
 .error(function(response) {alert('error');});
});
```

Control always goes to the error block. Pls help.

Comment: You have to add it to .json file

Comment: Does you server sent a response? Which code of response do you have?

Comment: By default there is html, head and body tags in html files. If you added json inside a html file, that json will be inside the body tags. You just have to replace htmlpage1.html with some .json file.

Comment: Yes, html is for displaying the data and not for storing it. Store your data inside in a Json file first.

Comment: Let me be clear. The requirement is to read the JSON returned by an Asp.Net WebApi controller which I am calling, not html to be exact. It's something like 'http://localhost:2587/api/expenses' which I am calling. That call is not returning anything via http get, even though the method in the controller is getting hit. Also the url returns json response on trying in browser

Comment: Weird thing is, the same $http.get code is able to read the JSON from the php page whose link I posted in the original post